# Book about a society too complex for humans to navigate unaided

Tags: story-identification

I remember this book, at least 10 years ago, probably more.  The main character was a person who, as punishment for a crime, had their cybernetic brain enhancement disabled. (Removed?)  This was a serious punishment indeed, because the futuristic society they lived in was so advanced that it was too complicated for an unaided human brain to make sense of.  Our protagonist was unable to function normally in civilization, or even really comprehend what crime it was they had committed and why it was wrong!

Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The book is most likely ["Psychohistorical Crisis" by Donald Kingsbury](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?22074).

The [Wikipedia page for it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychohistorical_Crisis) has a short plot synopsis:

> Eron Osa had been one of the Pscholars, the secret leaders behind the Second Empire of humanity. For a crime he cannot remember, he was sentenced, not to death, but to the removal of his fam, his symbiotic computer mind. Without the augmentation of his brain by his electronic familiar, he can barely function on Splendid Wisdom, the capital of the Empire. Without one, simply navigating the streets of the planetary megalopolis is nearly impossible. Worse, the traumatic removal has stolen large chunks of his memory, which were never stored in his biological brain. Eron must figure out what he did and why, and he must do so soon...

In the story, the brain enhancement is known as a "fam"